# My Developer Command Prompt build script stopped @echo-ing

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I have a build script that has been untouched and working right along (written by someone else - long gone).  Had lot's of @echo statements that kept me informed as to progress and problems.
@echo stopped working.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 (and Angular) and the script runs in the developer command prompt window.

Fortunately, I have a cryptic log file I can dig through, but it would be easiest for everyone if I had ANY knowledge about this subject.
Please recommend anything to help bring me up to speed: books, UDEMY, other tutorials, wizards, oracles, ... :-)
Chuck

Comment: I don't understand why this question has a `makefile` tag... there's nothing in here related to makefiles that I can see?

Comment: The echo commands are in the makefile.  That's where I figured the problem lie.

I finally rolled back the dev environment and the problem went away.